# Angular - Html Input value [Object Object]

Tags: angular

i have a reactive form that have one control with the following value:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  assetNum: [{'id': 1, 'value': 'Test'}]
});
```

How can i get the value in the input field?

```
<input type="text" formControlName="assetNum" />
```

because all i get is: [Object Object]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your FormBuilder specifies to create a FormGroup which takes a collection of child controls. You specify the control name as the key, in your case, assetNum, and the value as an array where you can specify the formState and then optionally, and validators or async validators.

```
// formState: any;
// validatorOrOpts: ValidatorFn | AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[]
// asyncValidators: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]

this.form = this.fb.group({
  controlName: [formState, validatorOrOpts?, asyncValidators?]
})
```

You text input field cannot accept an object as a formState (value). In order to get the value of the input field to show 'Test', you would have to build your form as follows:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  assetNum: ['Test']
})
```

Comment: Hi, what i want is have a input that receive a object value

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25750304)

Comment: Is the new post sufficient?